# Array Sort by gender

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

my list array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1000044375809533
            [likes] => 10
            [comments] => 6
            [posts] => 41
            [gender] => female
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1000043758049533
            [likes] => 10
            [comments] => 6
            [posts] => 41
            [gender] => male
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1000040382928633
            [likes] => 4
            [comments] => 0
            [posts] => 0
            [gender] => female
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1000003829428633
            [likes] => 4
            [comments] => 0
            [posts] => 0
            [gender] => male
        )
)
```

How do I set the list again by gender ?

And then sort by "total = likes + comments + posts"

total = 10
gender = male

total = 8
gender = male

total 10
gender = female

total = 7
gender = female

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['gender'] == $b['gender']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['gender'] < $b['gender']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

Comment: [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1000043758049533
            [likes] => 10
            [comments] => 6
            [posts] => 41
            [gender] => male
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1000003829428633
            [likes] => 4
            [comments] => 0
            [posts] => 0
            [gender] => male
        )